# Plotting CMAQ model output data from a NetCDF file

Tags: matlab, plot, mapping, netcdf

this is my first time working with NetCDF file formats so excuse my ignorance if I'm not asking this well.

I'm currently working in MATLAB with NetCDF data. The following is my code to view it:

```
clear all;
close all;
folder_name = uigetdir;

% Display the file contents
filename = 'CCTM_US1k.CONC.1km_HGB.2013244';
ncdisp(filename)
pathname2 = uigetdir('/projectnb/atmchem/ahsouri/MCIP')
filename2 = fullfile(pathname2, 'GRIDBDY2D_1km_HGB_2013242')
%% Read the Info
info = ncinfo(filename);
info2 = ncinfo(filename2);

%% Display the variables names
nVar = size(info.Variables, 2);
disp('Variable names are:')
for ii = 1:nVar
    disp(info.Variables(ii).Name);
end

nVar2 = size(info2.Variables, 2);
disp('Variable names are:')
for ii = 1:nVar2
    disp(info2.Variables(ii).Name);
end

%% Read Variables
Data = ncread(filename2,'LAT');
Data2 = ncread(filename2, 'LON');
Data3 = ncread(filename, 'NO2');

%% Mapping Texas
figure 
usamap('Texas')
Texashi = shaperead('usastatehi','UseGeoCoords', true, ...
    'Selector', {@(name) strcmpi(name,'Texas'), 'Name'});
geoshow(Texashi, 'FaceColor', [0.3 1.0, 0.675])

textm(Texashi.LabelLat, Texashi.LabelLon, Texashi.Name, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
geoshow(Data,Data2)
```

The data I'm viewing has the following attributes:
Their names within their files are:

```
Data = LAT (Obviously a latitude)
Data2 = LON (Longitude)
Data3 = NO2 (Obviously data regarding nitrogen dioxide)
```

NO2 comes from this file:

```
CCTM_US1k.CONC.1km_HGB.2013244
```

LAT and LON come from this file:

```
GRIDBDY2D_1km_HGB_2013242
```

The Following is the code I'm using to analyze the model output

```
size(Data)
ans = 
        1204

whos Data
Name      Size      Bytes    Class    Attributes
Data    1204x1       4816    Single

size(Data2)
ans = 
        1204
whos(Data2)
Name    Size     Bytes     Class     Attributes
Data2    1204x1   4816     single

size(Data3)
ans =
    336 264 27 25
whos(Data3)
Name     Size    Bytes    Class    Attributes
Data3    4-D   239500800  single
```

I'm just looking for any insight into how I might go about using MATLAB's mapping toolbox to properly plot gridded NO2 data onto the map of texas I've created. I'm currently able to plot the Latitude and longitude box just fine, I just don't know how to handle the NO2 data.

Any help is appreciated and I apologize for ignorance, I've tried to provide every bit of information at my disposal.

I'd also be more than open to see your solution to a similar problem within an alternative programming language!

Best,
Taylor

Comment: What is your expected output? A heatmap?

Comment: @Wolfie yes something of the sort.

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you have the [mapping toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping.html)? Can you confirm this and your MATLAB version...

Comment: @Wolfie Yes that is my question! I have version 2013a! Since I last asked I have discovered that the format of my NO2 file gives me "Lat, Lon, Altitude, and Timestamp by hour"